# Laravel: Is this the best way to receive products of category and it subcategories?

Tags: laravel, optimization, tree, eloquent

```
public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')->whereColumn('id', '!=', 'parent_id');
}

public function descendants()
{
    $descendants = [];

    foreach ($this->childs as $category) 
    {
        array_push($descendants, $category);
        $descendants = array_merge($descendants, $category->descendants());
    }

    return $descendants;
}

public function treeProducts()
{
    $categories = [$this];
    $categories = array_merge($categories, $this->descendants());

    $ids = [];

    forEach($categories as $category)
    {
        array_push($ids, $category->id);
    }

    return Product::whereIn('category_id', $ids)->get();
}
```

Any tips for optimization? I'm using Laravel 5.6, it's a better way to receive all products from a category (and it subcategories)?

I can't reproduce the treeProducts function with some Laravel Eloquent Relationship?

Comment: Did you try this package ? https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: @ysfkaya this package is creating an AVL tree?